# Slick comparing Rep[Option[ZonedDateTime]] to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, scala, slick

I'm trying to compare `ZonedDateTime` with following code:

```
val now = ZonedDateTime.now()

val query = for {
  x <- xTable.query if x === id
  if x.starts.isAfter(now) // Doesn't work
} yield x

...slick.run(query.result)
```

But it seems that I can't access `.isAfter` because `x.starts` is `Rep[Option[...]]`, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you just do something like `slick.run(xTable.filter(x => x.id == id && x.starts.isAfter(now)).result.headOption)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've described, it sounds like a suitable column type mapping might be missing.  For date/time [schemas](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/schemas.html), Slick only supports JDBC-based `java.sql.{Date, Time, Timestamp}`.  You would need an implicit mapper in scope wherever `ZonedDateTime` is used.  The mapper should look something like below:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import scala.slick.driver.JdbcProfile.MappedColumnType

implicit val zonedDateTimeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[ZonedDateTime, Timestamp](
  zdt => Timestamp.from(zdt.toInstant),
  ts => ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(ts.toInstant, ZoneOffset.UTC)
)
```